# Wrong output while adding two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to add up the columns but it's resulting in the wrong output.
ex: 1+2=3 
but i am getting 12 instead.

```
0       NaN
1        20
2        10
3       NaN
4       NaN
5        20
6        10
7        20
8       020
```

code used:

```
df.x+df.y
```

Comment: `df[x]+df[y]` Did you try this?

Comment: Maybe `1` and `2` are not numbers but strings.

Comment: @SivaShanmugam Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values are strings, so instead `sum` are joined together.

Solution is convert them to numeric:

```
s = df.x.astype(float)+df.y.astype(float)
```

If not working first solution because some data are not numeric, try [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` parameter for convert this values to `NaN`s:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df.x, errors='coerce')+pd.to_numeric(df.y, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Second one worked.